# Fabric Crashlytics and Twitter incompatibility

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I have main module where I want to setup Crashlytics and I have separate twitter module with Twitter oauth implementation. So I have 2 different points where I call Fabric.with(..) - first for Crashlytics, second for Twitter core.
But when Crashlitycs I enabled, twitter core is disabled.
How can I separate this 2 functionality in different modules?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lazy initialization of Fabric kits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284196/lazy-initialization-of-fabric-kits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

Only the first initialization of Fabric is respected, additional calls to implement Fabric after the first will not work. Currently, you would need to init both elements at the same time.